# Why doesn't this JS function properly import to my blade.php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, import

I have a JavaScript file, 'submittedForms.js' that I reference in my `blade.php` with

```
<script type="module" src="/js/bundle/charts/submittedForms.js"></script>
```

In `submittedForms.js`, I've defined a simple function called '*functionTest*' and a variable that represents a chart called '*submittedForms*'. I want to import both in my blade.php. The chart variable imports and is rendered fine! However, when I add the function and alter the export to be;

```
module.exports = {
    functionTest() {
        console.log('this works');
    },
    submittedForms
};
```

the following **error** thrown from the blade pops up;

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: functionTest is not defined"

In the `blade.php` I'm calling functionTest like this;

```
functionTest()
```

Comment: Why do you use `module.exports` in laravel code?

Comment: The second code snippet is from the JS file "submittedForms.js"

Comment: Are you also importing/requiring `submittedForms` into another `js` file?

Comment: No. Just the blade.php

Comment: Are you processing this file with Laravel Mix (or something else)?

Comment: Can you include the code where you call this function?

Comment: `module.exports` have to be in `key:value` pair and if you want to another module with this export,you need to import that module also in your current `export` file. Most important thing these functionality need to be compile with `babel` or `webpack` moduler to run in browser.

Comment: We are NOT using Laravel Mix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is because you're using `module.export` which is used for `importing/requiring` files between js file (this can be expanded on greatly but for the sake of the question I will keep it simple).

---

I would imagine that you're currently getting a warning in your console along the lines of:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined

---

To have you `functionTest` be available in your browser you can either define it as:

```
function functionTest() {
    console.log('this works');
}
```

which will attach it to the parent scope which in this case will be the `window`. Or you can explicitly attach it to the `window` object by:

or

```
window.functionTest = function () {
    console.log('this works');
}
```

---

If you're wanting to use the newer ES modules for importing/exporting this would be possible, however, support won't be that great at the time of writing.
To achieve this you should change `module.exports` to `export default`:

```
export default {
    functionTest() {
        console.log('this works');
    },
    submittedForms
};
```

Then in your blade file you could import it inside a script tag with the attribute `type="module"`:

```
<script type="module"> //notice the 

    import submittedForms from "/js/bundle/charts/submittedForms.js";

    submittedForms.functionTest();

</script>
```

Comment: So... what if I had a child JS file (```submittedForms.js```) with all my functions and variables defined, exported them out of the child with module.exports, then imported it into a single parent JS file (```aggregator.js```). Then I link ```aggregator.js``` into the blade.php? This is going off this MDN article, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: @ThirdGhostHand I have updated my answer to show how this would be possible with es modules.

Answer (score 0):

Right way to import JS file should look like this. Hopefully this will work.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/bundle/charts/submittedForms.js')}}"></script>
```